# How can I get the query strings to a url radio and submit button

Tags: string, url, button, hyperlink

I can not figure out how to get a HTML string to this url. I wanted to select the sixth option "For the amount of benefits you may be paid per week" and then select the continue button to take me to the page I wanted to start on. Why doesnt the link I created work and what would be the correct link and how was it figured out?

https://www.wvuc.org/wvweb/Welcome.aspx?UserOptions=6&bSubmit=Continue

**EDIT:**

What im trying to do is I have an excel userform that when opened, in that userform is the website page https://www.wvuc.org/wvweb/Welcome.aspx

What I wanted it to show instead of the first page is the page as if I seleced the radio option "For the amount of benefits you may be paid per week" and hit the continue or submit button and that is the page I wanted it to come up on when I first open my user form.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood your question properly, but what i assume is as follow.

Based on the selected option from radio buttons, you want to submit the current HTML FORM to option specific page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script language="javascript">
function setLink(obj) {

var url = "";
if (obj.value == 1) {
    url = "option1.html";
}
else if (obj.value == 2) {
    url = "option2.html";
}
else if (obj.value == 3) {
    url = "option3.html";
}

//now change the action attribute of form
//and form will be posted to updated link

document.frm1.action = url;


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm1" method="post" action="defaultlink.html">
<input type="radio" name="mylinks" onclick="setLink(this)" value="1" /> Option 1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="mylinks" onclick="setLink(this)" value="2" /> Option 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="mylinks" onclick="setLink(this)" value="3" /> Option 3<br>
<input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In above example as soon as you click on any of the radio button it will call a javascript function which will update the link of form where current form will be submitted.

Now when you click continue button the form will be submitted to the link changed(set) by javascript function.

I hope that might be the answer you are looking for, if its not please explain a bit more.

Thanks

Comment: Well what im trying to do is I have an excel userform that in that userform is the website page. What I wanted it to show instead of the first page is the page as if I seleced the Radio option and hit continue and that is the page I wanted it to come up on.

Comment: Above example is not answering your question?